# How to preserve custard apple?

Tags: storage-method, fruit

The shelf life of [custard apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custard_apple) is very short and also it is very delicate. How can I keep it fresh for a longer time? Till now I have tried freezing it and also keeping it in a air tight box but they didn't work. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In order to preserve your custard applies I would suggest canning them since you have already frezing it. It does lose it's freshness to an extent, however, the shelf life would last longer.

Canning is also a good method as is can use vacuum sealed packaging which restricts air into the packaging which is what causes micro-organism growth an multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sous-vide, or fermenting it depending on what you plan to do with it ?

Comment: Interesting approaches, do you have experience with these that you could share?

Comment: Sous vide is not a preservation method.

Comment: Sous-vide is a french word describing a cooking technique, yes, but also it is a way of just keeping food in a anaerobic environment, food that is subject to mold or insects for example. You just suck the air out of the bag and it preserves better than if you let it out.

Comment: Julie, do you mean “vacuum seal”? Could you please [edit] your post with the clarifications? And the asker wants to keep it fresh - I am not sure if fermenting fits here, as the process changes the product significantly.